# Strategy for mapping a function of several inputs and outputs using R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I would like want to plot a function of many inputs and outputs using R to study how some outputs depend on some inputs. My function is an economic model but, as a simple example, I write the function as

```
f <- function(x, y, z) {
  a = x * y^2
  return (data.frame(a, 
                     b = x + y + z,
                     c = sqrt(a)))
}
```

(I used a `data.frame` to return several outputs but am open to other suggestions - perhaps I should be taking a `data.frame` as input as well?)

Now, I want to plot `a` as a function of `x` when `y` and `z` are 1, then likewise plot `c` as a function of `y` and with `x` and `z` set to 2.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you try, re-wording, or perhaps describing in more detail what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I struggle to see how this is question can possibly be unclear but I attempted to clarify it nonetheless. Perhaps you can explain what you find confusing?